# laravel how to get all the users i talked to

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i am now working on a messaging system with laravel. Now i want to have a list of users the current user send message to / receive from. suppose i have a message table like

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | msg
1  | 1         | 2           | smadksamdksa
2  | 3         | 4           | hi
3  | 1         | 2           | www
4  | 2         | 1           | ssse
5  | 3         | 1           | hi
```

i find get a list of id of user i talked to, the result for the user 1 will be

```
id
2
3
```

model of message

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class msg extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'msgs';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
    }
}
```

the query i made

```
$senders = msg::select('sender_id')->where('receiver_id', '=', Auth::id())->distinct()->get();
$peopleUserTalkedTo = msg::select('receiver_id')->where('sender_id', '=', Auth::id())->distinct()->union($senders)->get();
```

but it doesn't work with an error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$bindings
```

what's wrong with it, and can i SELECT sender id and receiver AS id, can i get the user id from it later on?

I think the problem is about the union method.

Comment: not sure but does the Auth::id() works? i thaught its Auth::user()->id (or they are the same? )

Comment: @Jerryc According to your table, user 1 has talked to only user 2, then how can you get 2 & 3?

Comment: @RohitKhatri oh sorry for my english, i mean the user have conversation related to user 1

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja i think Auth::id() works, however Auth::user()->id doesn't help

Comment: And i think the problem is about union method

Comment: @Jerryc Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should define your models like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class msg extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'msgs';

    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user','sender_id');
    }

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user','receiver_id');
    }    
}


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    public function talkedTo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\msg','sender_id');
    }

    public function relatedTo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\msg','receiver_id');
    }
}
```

Now try to fetch people you talked to like this:

```
Auth::user()->talkedTo()->get();
Auth::user()->relatedTo()->get();
```

**Updated**

For getting only ids of the people you talked to or related to follow the code:

```
Auth::user()->talkedTo->pluck('id');
Auth::user()->relatedTo->pluck('id');
```

Comment: thanks @Rohit Khatri, is the code getting all message records related to auth user, but can i get a list of user i send msg to or get from first with this

Comment: @Jerryc Yes you can get a list of users you talked to using this `Auth::user()->talkedTo()->get();` and you can change the name of `function talkedTo()` with whatever you want.

Comment: sorrry i am new to laravel, don't know if it is my problem, the result of it should record id 1 , 3, 4, 5? what can i do if i want only the id of user on the other side which is user id  2 and 3

Comment: @Jerryc If the above solution worked for you, please mark it as the right answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

didnt realy get what u want but Try this after being sure to add  this to ur user model

```
class user extends Model
{

    public function msgs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\msg');
    }
}
```

**then**

```
$mymsgs = Auth::user()->msgs->get(); //collection of all msgs
```

and then you can use a foreach loop

Comment: i want to have a list of users the current user send message to / receive from.